# Kann man einen See restaurieren?

Tags: semantics

> "Der massiv mit Blaualgen belastete Barleber See in Magdeburg kann
>   restauriert werden."

31.1.19, https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/sachsen-anhalt-aluminiumsalze-sollen-blaualgen-problem-im.2850.de.html?drn:news_id=971816

Kann man einen See **restaurieren** bzw. kann man **einen See** restaurieren? **Wasser** generell? Ist der *restaurierbare (?) See* eine akzeptable Neuerung oder eine (grobe?) sprachliche Verirrung?

Comment: Ähm, warum soll man diesen Begriff denn **nicht** nehmen dürfen? Das müßtest du schon erläutern.

Comment: Vielleicht sollten einige Stauseen wieder mal gründlich restauriert werden. Nein, jetzt aber im Ernst: Ich bin vor ein paar Jahren über einen Songtext gestolpert, da hiess es: „ Holy Spirit - restore my soul.“ Von daher ist mir das Restaurieren in anderen Zusammenhängen als nur von Bildern, Statuen und Gebäuden vertraut. Bei „sanieren“ könnte es jemandem gleich ergehen, dessen Verständnis von „sanieren“ auf die Gesundheit beschränkt. Aber selbst wenn dieser Gebrauch eine Stilblüte wäre: Sprache ist immer im Wandel, und Übertragungen werden immer einmal von jemandem zum ersten Mal kreiert.

Comment: @takkat - Ach, na ja, müssen müsste ich gar nichts. Ich orientiere mich stattdessen an Valenzen und Distributionen und erhobenen Fakten, z.B. hier: https://www.dwds.de/wp/restaurieren . Dort kommen u.a. *Fluss, See, Wasser* nicht vor.

Answer (score 7):

Restaurieren kommt aus dem Lateinischen und bedeutet "einen früheren Zustand wiederherstellen".

Es ist also weder eine Neuerung, noch eine Verirrung. Zumindest nicht vom Autor deines Zitats.

> restaurieren
>   ausbessern (Kunstwerk), wiederherstellen (frühere Zustände)
>   ♦
>   frz.
>   restaurer in ders. Bed., auslat.
>   restaurare „wiederherstellen, erneuern, wieder erbauen“, auslat.
>   re– „wieder“ undgriech.
>   stauroun „einen Pfahl errichten, einschlagen“, zugriech.
>   stauros „Pfahl“
>   [1](https://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/restaurieren)

Answer (score 6):

Ja, man kann ein Gewässer oder einen anderen ökologischen Lebensraum restaurieren. Restaurieren bedeutet dabei, dass man versucht den natürlichen/naturnahen Zustand, der vor dem Eingegriff des Menschen bestanden hat, wiederherzustellen.

Aus dem [Leitfaden zur Renaturierungvon Feuchtgebieten in Brandenburg](https://lfu.brandenburg.de/cms/media.php/lbm1.a.3310.de/lua_bd50.pdf):

> Die  wichtigsten  **Restaurierungsmaßnahmen**  (siehe auch KALETTKA 1996) sind: Sanierung und Wiederherstellung von Binneneinzugsgebieten (siehe Kap. 1.5.1.1), Rückbau von Entwässerungssystemen,...

Da das leider nur selten funktioniert (der menschliche Einfluss ist überall) und es auch die philosophische Frage aufwirft, ob man einen menschlichen Eingriff durch einen anderen menschlichen Eingriff rückgängig machen und den natürlichen Zustand wiederherherstellen kann, spricht man in der Ökologie meist von **Renaturierung** oder **Revitalisierung** (siehe auch "Biodiversität: Grundlagen, Gefährdung, Schutz (2014) von Rüdiger Wittig, Manfred Niekisch; Seite 432" )

Comment: Danke für den Link und den Auszug. Danke auch für die Bestätigung von *renaturieren* und *revitalisieren*, die **ich** in diesem Satz verwendet hätte.